# Hyperledger Composer error: status: 500, message: chaincode exists

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I started a new composer network (two org setup), i.e. a second chaincode (one was already installed and running). I installed it and while starting, couple of chaincode containers were stuck while downloading node modules, and the command to start chaincode was timed out. To start again I removed the chaincode containers and tried to start again. But I am getting error : `status: 500, message: chaincode exists.`

Comment: Check for the chaincode namespace. Also, if you could brief  the steps, would be helpful for others to answer ?

Answer (score 0):

That message from hyperledger fabric means that the chaincode has already been instantiated, so you do not need to invoke `composer network start` again. Any request you send to a peer will try to bring up a chaincode container to process that request if there isn't one already started. 
`composer network start` sends the instantiate transaction to peers and as such the peers need to simulate the request proposal and to do that it needs a chaincode container so goes through the process of creating a chaincode container image and chaincode container to execute the request (but any transaction proposal causes the same process to be followed). So long as the instantiation policy is satisfied (and the default I believe is for 1 successful instantiation proposal) then the chaincode is then defined as instantiated.